# Is there any way to convert this into django orm?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I needed to get all the rows in the `table1` even if it is not existing in `table2` and display it as zero. I got it using `raw sql query` but in **django ORM** i am getting the values existing only in `table2`. The only **difference on my django orm is that iI am using inner join while in the raw sql query I am using left join.** Is there any way to achieve this or should I use raw sql query? Thanks.

**Django ORM:**

```
total=ApplicantInfo.objects.select_related('source_type').values('source_type__source_type').annotate(total_count=Count('source_type'))
```

**OUTPUT OF DJANGO ORM IN RAW SQL:**

```
SELECT "applicant_sourcetype"."source_type", COUNT("applicant_applicantinfo"."source_type_id") AS "total_count" FROM "applicant_applicantinfo" INNER JOIN "applicant_sourcetype" ON ("applicant_applicantinfo"."source_type_id" = "applicant_sourcetype"."id") GROUP BY "applicant_sourcetype"."source_type"
```

**RAW SQL:**

```
SELECT source.source_type, count(info.source_type_id) as total_counts from applicant_sourcetype as source LEFT JOIN applicant_applicantinfo as info ON source.id = info.source_type_id GROUP BY source.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query on `ApplicantInfo` if you want a left join with it. Query on `SourceType` instead:

```
qs = (SourceType.objects
    .values('source_type')
    .annotate(cnt=Count('applicantinfo'))
    .values('source_type', 'cnt')
)
```

Since you haven't posted the models, you may need to adapt the field names to make it work.